# Ubuntu One Client 3.02b stuck at "File Sync Starting" on Windows XP 32-bit

Tags: ubuntu-one-windows

I have been using Ubuntu One on Natty on my laptop and (sad) Win-XP 32-bit on my desktop. At first, the sync function worked well on both platforms but now it's stuck at "File sync starting" on Win-XP 32-bit.

I have already tried to uninstall it completely (removed device, deleted folder, restarted pc) and reinstall it but no luck. It is able to display a list of "My Personal Folders" though.

I did some Google-ing and found someone had similar problem on Win7 64-bit and some said the bug is resolved since version 3. Unfortunately that's not the case for me. As the title suggests, I am running v3.02b on WinXP.

Any help / comments would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer was:

1. Clean drive from Ubuntu One (unistall, erase logs, directories, clean registry with ccleaner)
2. Rename folder Uubuntu One in *user* (i.e. ubuntuone.old)
3. Reboot.
4. Fresh new install of latest version (4.1.91.1)
5. It worked. Don't know why.

Within Ubuntu pangolin never failed.